# How to share image on istagram?

Tags: android, api, instagram

**Hello every one**

Is there any tutorial to share image on instagram without using the share intent. Till now ihave used the share intent but . Problem is this if instagram is not installed on phone then it will not upload image . So i want to upload image like facebook is doing Please help me.

**Thanks**

Comment: Just a quite search in Google and I already found results for that.. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=instagram+api+android+tutorial

Comment: i think instagram doesn't provide upload image API for more read http://instagram.com/developer/

Comment: so then how we can share image on it

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to post an image to Instagram except through the Instagram app.